# Getting syntax error involving ';'

Tags: c#

I am making a pokemon game and this section is giving me 3 errors:
"Invalid expression term ';' (CS1525)" and "; expected(CS1002)"

```
public class HeldItem
{
    public static int CritCalc(bool item,bool skill, bool UsedItem,int dmg)
    {
        Random rand=new Random();
        Action jump=new Action();
        int i = rand()%100;
        double CritPerc = 6.25;
        if(item==true)
            CritPerc=12.5;
        else if(skill==true)
            CritPerc=12.5;
        else if(UsedItem==true)
            CritPerc=12.5;
        else if((item==true & skill== true) || (item==true & UsedItem == true) || (skill==true & UsedItem==true))
                CritPerc=25%;
        else if(item==true & skill == true & UsedItem==true)
            CritPerc=33.3%;
        if(Action) //jump
            CritPerc = 50%;
        if(i<CritPerc)
            dmg=2*dmg;
        else if(i>CritPerc)
            dmg==dmg;
        return dmg; 
    }
}
```

}

Maybe it is a silly problem but I don't know what it is

Comment: You probably intend to use `&&` (logical) instead of `&` (bitwise).

Comment: Just by a quick look at things, CritPerc = 25% doesn't make sense. It should either be .25 or "25%". The same is true in two other places in the code. Edited: since CritPerc is double, it should be 25.0 based on your convention.

Comment: @Pubby - The & operator performs a bitwise logical AND operation on integral operands and logical AND on bool operands. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02

Comment: This doesn't do anything: `else if(i>CritPerc)
        dmg==dmg;`

Comment: The error you are getting is because of the "%", other than that... You use Action as both a type and a variable. I think you intended to call jump, like so: jump(); I also want to mention that the constructor for Action needs an argument, unless it is a custom made class (in which case, you don't call jump like so: jump();) And comparing dmg==dmg is a warning because it doesn't make sense to compare a variable to itself.

Comment: @AVD I know, but many would consider `&&` to be clearer. Anyway, he could also remove the `== true`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot specify percents in C#.

You have the following lines:

```
CritPerc=25%;
CritPerc=33.3%;
CritPerc = 50%;
```

That is invalid (Percent indicates the modulo operator in C#).

Instead, you probably want to specify the values as double floating point values.

```
CritPerc=0.25;
CritPerc=0.333;
CritPerc = 0.50;
```

Comment: Ironically `i` was obtained using that very modulus operator.

Answer (score 2):

> %(percent) operator in c# means modulo operation which takes two
>   operand. but you give one. So it gives error.

Instead of

```
CritPerc=25%;
```

write

```
CritPerc=.25;
```

or

```
CritPerc=25/100;
```

and

> dmg==dmg

causes error.

Answer (score 1):

The line that says:

```
dmg == dmg;
```

Ah, the fatal '=' error.

Answer (score 1):

You have dmg ==dmg  which is the wrong operator and if dmg already has the correct value just return it, dmg=dmg goes without saying